# Java possible race condition of Collection in -- spring framework

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, race-condition

I am using the spring framework under tomcat to write  service that can handle multiple concurrent requests. There is a static variable declared in my service class to be shared across all the threads and protected by a read-write lock. This static collection is read and written to periodically. Each time  I update I acquire the write lock and when I read it I acquire the read lock.

The data stored in the collection is entries from a database table. So it is a collection of type List. Basically I have a table that gets updated rarely and so I am caching it in the process memory.

Now there are times when I need to log this data so can I log the return object without acquiring the lock in the method. Or will that cause a race condition? The logging is for the purpose of debugging.

Also, the returned value of the collection is only read only and is not modified by any method. No one outside of the service object uses this Collection.

I feel this should work because when a new collection is allocated the old collection will only go away if all references to it have gone away. And while updating no new references to old or new object are allowed till the write lock is unlocked.

The code looks as follows:

```
class ObjService {
    
    private static Collection<OtherObj> _staticCollection;
    private static ReentrantReadWriteLock rwlock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);
    
    private Collection<OtherObj> getCollection () {
       Collection<OtherObj> retVal = null;

       rwlock.readLock().lock();
       if (_staticCollection != null) {
         retVal = _staticCollection;
         rwlock.readLock().unlock();
         log (retVal);
       }
       else {
          rwlock.readLock().unlock();
          ReloadCollectionFromDB ();
          rwlock.readLock().lock();
          retVal = _staticCollection;
          rwlock.readLock().unlock();
       }
    }

    private ReloadCollectionFromDB  () {
      Collection<OtherObj> otherObjCol = null;

      try {
         otherObjCol = objRepo.findAll ();
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
         // log exception
         return;
      }

      rwlock.writeLock().lock();
      _staticCollection = otherObjCol;
      rwlock.writeLock().unlock();
    }


    // periodically get data from DB
    @Scheduled(initialDelayString = "120000", fixedDelayString = "540000")
    void readLoadCache () {
       ReloadCollectionFromDB ();
    }
}
```

If there are better ways of doing this, I would appreciate some guidance.

Many thanks,
~Ash

Comment: Basically, for logging you need to read the collection, so you need to lock the readLock to do it safely. What exactly could go wrong if you don't depends on the concrete type of collection and can't be answered in general.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve in your `getCollection()` method? The second assignment to the local `retVal` variable doesn't have any effect, is this just for debugging?

Comment: What I have just said applies to mutable collections - I assumed that Collection is not immutable. It seems you only protect the assignments of the reference at the moment - this won't be enough if the collection can be modified by other threads (elements added, removed or modified).

Comment: You are correct that the return value can be modified by the caller but this method is private and all the callers use this for read only.

Comment: The logging is for debugging purposes only.
In the method <code>getCollection()</code> the first assignment is for when the collection is not null and the second assignment is after the collection is first initialized.

Comment: Updated the original question to show the intent of the collection and why I think this should work. Would appreciate some guidance.